# Session is outdated or not initialized while sending Request

Tags: automated-testing, rest-api, rest-assured

When I send POST request to the server for SignUp I receive an error that session is outdated or not initialized. How could it be solved?

```
// create request
@BeforeClass
private void createRequestSpecification() {
    test_user = new User();
    requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder().
            setBaseUri(ApiTestBase.currentEnvironment.getUrl()).
            setPort(443).
            setContentType(ContentType.JSON).
            setBasePath("/Server/user/registerUser").
            build();
}
// post request
@Test
private void correctSignUp() {
    Response response = given().
            spec(requestSpec).
            and().
            queryParam("companyName", test_user.getCompany()).
            queryParam("firstName", test_user.getFName()).
            queryParam("lastName", test_user.getLName()).
            queryParam("loginName", test_user.getEmail()).
            queryParam("password", DigestUtils.sha256Hex(test_user.getPass())).
            when().
            post().
            then().
            log().all().
            assertThat().statusCode(200).
            and().
            extract().
            response();
    checkIfSignUp(true, response);
}
```

**Response**

```
    <body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
    <hr class="line"/>
    <p>
    <b>Type</b>
 Exception Report 
    <p>
    <b>Message</b>
 Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: session is outdated or not initialized, re-login    </p>
    <p>
    <b>Description</b>
 The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.    </p>
    <p>
    <b>Exception</b>
    </p>
    <pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: session is outdated or not initialized, re-login
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre>
    <p>
      <b>Root Cause</b>
    </p>
    <pre>java.lang.RuntimeException: session is outdated or not initialized, re-login
    com.novisign.server.user.controller.SessionSecureData.get(SessionSecureData.java:37)
    com.novisign.server.user.controller.UserController.registerUser(UserController.java:306)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor855.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre>
```

Comment: I am not sure queryParam is the proper method to send credentials data. Try to use `params(...)` instead

Comment: It doesn't work this way. Login tests works Ok even with queryParam using POST, but SignUp tests don't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cookies should be sent with Request.